# Ring With Infinitely Many Ideals but Proper has only Finitely Many

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am looking for a commutative ring R with identity, with infinitely many ideals, yet every proper ideal contains (as a subset) only finitely many ideals of R.  I know such a ring cannot be Artin (because Artin rings have only a finite number of max ideals, so one of them contains infinitely many proper ideals) I also know Artin implies either Not Noetherian or nozero Krull dimension.  Does such a ring exist?  I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 4):

Such a ring is trivially Artinian: any descending chain of ideals must terminate, since as soon as you reach a proper ideal it has only finitely many subideals.  But, as you observe, such a ring cannot be Artinian.  Thus no such ring exists.

Comment: Thank you Eric Wofsey!  This answer was so close to me, I completely overlooked it!  Thanks again!